# Save changes in BindingList with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

There is winform grid for editing data. Filling data (simplifed code):

```
var regions = context.RegionViews;
var bindinglist = new BindingList<RegionView>(regions.ToList());
gridControl.DataSource = (IBindingList) bindinglist;
```

Saving data with the same context:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

But only edit changes are saved, not added and deleted rows.

Comment: Are you adding the new items to your `context`? Adding items to your `bindingList` is not the same as adding them to your data context.

Comment: I felt something wrong with my code. I have to add logic that identify new and deleted entities and then loop through my list?

Comment: That... or use the tools provided by Entity Framework (the `Local` collection in your `DbSet`)

Comment: read about problems with performance of Local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `BindingList<RegionView>` out of a new list (the one created with `regions.ToList()`) so the changes to the records are saved (since the references in the list also point to the `DbSet` contained objects), but the original `DbSet` doesn't know items are being added or removed (since they are added/removed from that list, and not from the `DbSet`)

Instead of creating a new `BindingList` directly, try setting the `DataSource` to the local observable list of the `DbSet` (I'm assuming `context.RegionViews` is a `DbSet`)

```
gridControl.DataSource = context.RegionViews.Local.ToBindingList();
```